# Using systemd, how to auto-restart services A and B whenever A crashes?

Tags: linux, systemd

B depends on A. Whenever A crashes, I'd like systemd to restart A **and B**.

#### What I've been able to do

With `BindsTo=a.service` and `After=a.service` written in `b.service` file, manually restarting A (with command `systemctl restart a`) causes systemd to:

1. stop B;
2. stop A;
3. start A;
4. start B;

which is the expected behavior.

However, simulating a crash of A (with command `killall -SIGKILL a`) causes systemd to:

1. stop B;
2. "stop" A (it's crashed at this point anyway);
3. start A;

and that's it. **No restart of B is performed**.

#### What my `.service` files look like now

`a.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=A

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
UMask=007
ExecStart=/usr/bin/a
Restart=on-failure
TimeoutStopSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`b.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=B
After=a.service
BindsTo=a.service
PartOf=a.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
UMask=007
ExecStart=/usr/bin/b
Restart=always
TimeoutStopSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use either `PartOf=` or `BindsTo=` not both of them.

Using both options would result in them conflicting with each other and lead to unexpected results.